# How to change Server Time Zone in Opencart?

Tags: php, timezone, opencart, opencart2.x

We use Opencart 1.5.6 and our server time is Eastern Time, but our shop is in Pacific time...
How do we change the server time for our store?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the timezone in your index.php with `ini_set()`.  You also need to set the MySQL timezone since OpenCart queries use `NOW()` quite often.

```
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Los_Angeles');
$db->query("SET time_zone = '" . date('P') . "'");
```

Make sure you add this to **both** index.php files - admin and catalog, somewhere after:

```
$registry->set('db', $db);
```

Answer (score 1):

OC sets the time zone to `UTC` if the value of `date.timezone` in `php.ini` file is not defined
You can find that piece of code in `<OC_ROOT>/system/startup.php`

```
if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

So you just need to change this piece of code, or re-define the value `date.timezone`